# What do we know about Hagrid's father? Was he a wizard?

Tags: harry-potter

Hagrid grew up with his father.  We know his mother has left them when he was a child, leaving the father heart-broken.  We also know the father wasn't giant-sized (Hagrid could lift him when he was a small kid).  There seems to be very little else we know about him.

So I'd like to ask what we know about Hagrid's father.  In particular, what species was he, and was he a wizard or a Muggle?  If he was a Muggle, how was Hagrid introduced to the wizarding world?

Comment: I thought Hagrid explicitly mentioned his father being a wizard at some point in the books, but perhaps I'm misremembering.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Rubeus_Hagrid's_father

Comment: @mikeazo - Wikia isn't always canon unless it has cites and sources.

Comment: @DVK, I kind of figured that (new to the site) which is why I only linked as a comment.

Comment: I remember when Hagrid was talking to madam Maxime, he told that his mother was gient & his father was a normal wizard. He could pick his father with one hand and put him on a dressing table. So he became half gient..

Comment: @Rajan: Like I say in a comment to DVK, I don't think Hagrid tells that to Madame Maxime.  If you think he does, find the exact quote and post it as an answer.

Comment: @b_jonas : He already posted exact quote from the book.. I don't want to duplicate the answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Hagrid's father was a wizard:

> Hagrid got up, went over to his dresser, opened a drawer and pulled out a **picture of a short wizard** with Hagrid's crinkled black eyes, beaming as he sat on top of Hagrid's shoulder. Hagrid was a good seven or eight feet tall, judging by the apple tree beside him, but his face was beardless, young, round and smooth – he looked hardly older than eleven.
>
> 'Tha' was taken jus' after I got inter Hogwarts,' said Hagrid, croakily. 'Dad was dead chuffed – **thought I migh' not be a wizard**, see, 'cos me mum – well, anyway. 'Course, I never was great shakes at magic, really – but at least he never saw me expelled. Died, see, in me second year
>
> (GoF, Chapter 24)

---

I don't think it was ever mentioned in canon if he was a Muggle or not.

But since Giants don't seem to be a big-time magic users, and Hagrid can do magic with a wand, it stands to reason that Hagrid most likely inherited it from his father (not certain since there are fully Muggle-born wizards even from 2 human parents)

The second bit of circumstantial evidence is that he married Hagrid's mom. I'm pretty sure a Muggle wouldn't have survived a couple of years of marriage to a giantess without ending up Muggle-shaped Pancaked Carpet.

Comment: Agreed, and would like to add that to procreate the two of them would have to meet and communicate, two things that from the texts would seem impossible for a muggle. Giants like magic -- she would have listened to anything he had to say if he did a few tricks.

Comment: Nice!  I missed this one.  I was looking in chapter 23 only, where Hagrid is talking to Madame Maxime.