# How many Wizards/ Witches got into relationships with Muggles?

Tags: harry-potter

A discussion arose in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119849/how-were-there-so-many-couplings-between-witches-wizards-and-muggles) about how rare it was for witches/ wizards to get into relationships with Muggles.

I was under the impression that it was fairly common, as I could immediately bring to mind at least three people who were conceived of this type of relationship:

- Dean Thomas
- Severus Snape
- Tom Riddle (Voldemort)

Are there many other wizards/ witches in canon who had relationships/ marriages/ families with Muggles? (Not including squibs).

Comment: Related question, has a few more characters: [Of all the half-Muggles in JKR work, what is the percentage of those with muggle mother vs father?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46594/of-all-the-half-muggles-in-jkr-work-what-is-the-percentage-of-those-with-muggle)

Comment: i'd say ^ answers the question perfectly